Integrating an External React Component from an HTTP Server into React App
I'm working on a project where I need to serve a React component (plugin.js) from an HTTP server (e.g., http://example.com) and then use this component inside another React application.
The goal is to load and integrate the plugin.js file dynamically into my React app as a plugin or external module. However, I'm encountering some errors while attempting this integration.
Has anyone successfully implemented this kind of setup before? I would appreciate any guidance, tips, or examples on how to serve and use a React component from an external HTTP server within a React application.
Thank you!

Maybe you should add what errors you are encountering
